# Grenade arc in 3D

Tags: mathematics

I'm wondering what the math would be to getting a grenade arc (like you're throwing it). In my game you would know the point in 3D that you'd be aiming at so the idea would be to arc it from it's starting point to exactly that point, but I'm not sure of the math on getting all the points between so I can smoothly move it without physics. Any advice or pointing in a direction would be great. Thank you!

Comment: See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17467/calculating-velocity-needed-to-hit-target-in-parabolic-arc?rq=1

Comment: Also, you can do a search on "parabola" here and you will find a bunch of useful already solved question. And don't limit yourself to "3d" as it's the exact same thing in "2d".

Comment: ty. I wasn't aware that's what it was called. That'll help a ton.